# GoLang multithreading server

Tags: многопоточность, сокет, golang

Суть задачи такова:
Есть многопоточный TCP сервер на Go

```
func main() {
    reportSocket, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8080")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) 
    }

    mirrorSocket, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:9090")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) 
    }

    fmt.Printf("Server running on %s", reportSocket.Addr().String())
    fmt.Printf("Gate running on %s", mirrorSocket.Addr().String())

    go func() {
        for {
            mirror, err := mirrorSocket.Accept()
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            go handleMirrorConnection(mirror)
        }
    }()

    for {
        report, err := reportSocket.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        go handleReportConnection(report)
    }
}

func handleReportConnection(report net.Conn) {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", report.RemoteAddr().String())
    // Some stuff

    report.Close()
}

func handleMirrorConnection(mirror net.Conn) {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", mirror.RemoteAddr().String())
    mirror.Close()
}
```

Необходимо передать данные из reportSocket в mirrorSocket
То есть, при подключении к порту 8080, все данные переданные пользователем  должны быть переданы другому пользователю, слушающему 9090 порт

Как сие реализовать?

Comment: А как вы пользователей друг от друга отличите?

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос :)